# How to get verify entitlement node on unreal engine for oculus?

Tags: unreal-engine4, game-development, oculus

I am using unreal engine 4.23 and trying to use Online Subsystems. I have enabled the plugin, restarted, edited the DefaultEngine file, restarted again, and I do not have a "Verify Entitlement" node. According to all documentation I can find, it should pop up now, but I cannot seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

The Verify Entitlement node derives from the Online Subsystem *Oculus* plugin. There are many Online Subsystems Plugins, perhaps you selected the wrong one? Also, it may help to turn off the "Context Sensitive" filter when searching in your Blueprint graph. Keep me up to date on this one! I don't know if this answer will fix this, but I hope it at least helps.

Comment: Hi. I came across the same issue. I have OculusSubsystem Plugin activated. What could be wrong? Thanks

Comment: Same issue here with UE 4.27. I followed all the instructions from the Oculus Start Guide, but had no luck.